# Ошибка при установке pocketsphinx

Tags: python, python-3.x, pocketsphinx

Устанавливаю pocketsphinx. Скачал swig, но даже после этого получил ошибку:

```
Command "c:\users\elena\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Elena\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v47abr4g\\pocketsphinx\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Elena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-k3_p_5qq\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Elena\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-v47abr4g\pocketsphinx\
```

Answer (score 0):

Я скачивал по другому, и у меня получилось

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
pipwin install pocketsphinx
```

Comment: а точно с большой буквы?

Comment: Извините, не понял?

Comment: у вас было написано `Pip` и `Pipwin`. как видите, я уже исправил ваш ответ, но на всякий случай спросил.